# Can I specify environment variables in SLF4J Simple's props file?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, environment-variables, slf4j

According to [this link](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/SimpleLogger.html) SLF4J Simple can be configured by putting a `simplelogger.properties` file on the runtime classpath.

An example of `simplelogger.properties`:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=/home/myuser/.myapp/logs/myapp.log
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=INFO
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets=false
```

But what if I wanted my app to define its own environment variable, say, `MYAPP_HOME`, and set it to a value of `/home/myuser/.myapp/logs`. How would I then reference the `MYAPP_HOME` variable from inside `simplelogger.properties`? Is this even possible?

For example, could I do:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile=${MYAPP_HOME}/logs/myapp.log
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=INFO
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.levelInBrackets=false
```

**Note**: the above doesn't work and causes the following exception:

```
Could not open [${MYAPP_HOME}/logs/myapp.log]. Defaulting to System.err
Reported exception:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${MYAPP_HOME}/logs/myapp.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:99)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.computeTargetStream(SimpleLogger.java:224)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.init(SimpleLogger.java:205)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger.<init>(SimpleLogger.java:268)
    at org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleLoggerFactory.java:57)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
    ... rest of stack trace omitted for brevity
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `simplelogger.properties` is read as a normal Java [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file by `SimpleLogger`, references to environment variables are not resolved within.

You can however provide the path in an environment variable named `org.slf4j.simpleLogger.logFile`, which is also read by `SimpleLogger` and takes precedence over configuration via `simplelogger.properties`.